# Installation Problems Acer 4750G Ubuntu 12.04 Dual Boot

Tags: 12.04, installation, dual-boot, acer

I've been playing with Ubuntu the past few weeks via WUBI and finally decided to give it its own space in my HDD through dual booting via separate partitions.

After installation, the system could not detect Ubuntu, even after explicitly adding Grub2 via EasyBCD.

Desperate for answers, I Googled and came across this:

http://www.worldofnubcraft.com/1825/grub2-issues-with-ubuntu-12-04-installation/

and also another post

http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1434354.html

And right now, my computer won't boot up anymore, it just says `Operating System not Found`.

Comment: as an update, i tried ubuntu 32 bit and works fine. but now it wont detect my USB broadband stick .. :(

Answer (score 1):

Just try this and it will probably work: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: Linked answer are generally not allowed here. Best to copy the essentials here, in case the site is down.

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, it would be preferred that you post the key points of a link here.